# SQL AVG with values not null

Tags: sql, null, average

I have a table colour:

```
white NULL
white 5
red 3
red 7
blue 6
blue 4
```

I want an avg function to take avg of the colours. AVG function ignore the 'white NULL' row as it has null. I want it to ignore colour white altogether. I want it to display only

```
red  5
blue 5
```

Can't figure out how to ignore 'category' of values with one null

Answer (score 1):

Filter off the unwanted colors using a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    color,
    AVG(value) AS avg_value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY color
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```